# How to use notistack in Nextjs 13+

Tags: next.js, next.js13, notistack

I am having an issue using notistack in nextjs 13+.

I'd usually wrap the {children} with the SnackbarProvider, like so:

```
<SnackbarProvider>
{children}
</SnackbarProvider>
```

inside the _app file, but with nextjs 13+ it is now the layout file. How do i get this done, without turning my layout file into a 'use client'.
I have tried using a customerprovider, but I am getting the same

```
TypeError: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'use client' directive at the top of the SnackbarProvider component file because you used the `createContext` hook which works on the client side.

Comment: The snackbar component is provided. I can only add 'use client' to the top of the layout file, which i am trying not to do. The only workaround I find so far, is to add the SnackbarProvider on each pages I need to see it

Comment: I'm saying this when you return CustomProvider it should look like this, <globalContext.Provider value={{ foo: "bar" }}>
      <SnackbarProvider>{children}</SnackbarProvider>
    </globalContext.Provider> In a separate component and at the top you should use the 'use client' directive.